# mootools equivalent of jQuery's .is()

Tags: mootools

Does Mootools have the equivalent of jQuery's .is()? Or if not, what's the best approach for this functionality in Mootools? I've searched for a while and can't seem to find the right solution.

Example of jQuery I'm trying to achieve in Mootools.

```
if(a.is(':last-child')){
   console.log('this should return true >', a.is(':last-child'));
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know of a Mootools equivalent, but you can probably the [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) `matches()` function. [Other Link](https://davidwalsh.name/element-matches-selector)

```
var bd = document.body;
console.log(bd.matches('body')) //true
console.log(bd.matches(':last-child')) //true
```

Comment: Thanks philipp, this works just fine for what I need.